# If there is no inherent in Golang, how can I try to build it

Tags: go, inheritance

The struct in Golang does not have a constructor, and we can generally use the factory pattern to solve this problem. But how can I try to implement inheritance in the factory pattern?
For example, here are some of my code:

In student.go

```
package model

//a struct
type student struct{
 Name string
 score float64
}

//Because the initial letter of the student structure is lowercase, it can only be used in mods
func NewStudent(n string, s float64) *student {
 return &student{
  Name : n,
  score : s,
 }
}

//If the first letter of the score field is lowercase, then, in other packages not directly method, we can provide a method
func (s *student) GetScore() float64{
 return s.score //ok
}
```

In main.go

```
package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "factory/model"
)

func main() {
 //Create the Student instance to be given
 // var stu = model.Student{
 //  Name :"tom",
 //  Score : 78.9,
 // }

 //If the student structure is lowercase, we can solve it by using the factory pattern
 var stu = model.NewStudent("tom~", 98.8)

 fmt.Println(*stu) //&{....}
 fmt.Println("name=", stu.Name, " score=", stu.GetScore())
}
```

How can I try to implement inheritance in code?

Answer (score 5):

> How can I try to implement inheritance in code?

You cannot. Whatever you try: You will fail.

You have to model your problem *without* inheritance.

(Inheritance conflates several things: Code reuse and behaviour. In Go code reuse is done through functions and behaviour through interfaces.)